# Cast type during round up in Swift

Tags: swift, pow

I have the following warning:

```
var ifloor:Float = 10.1
var arredondado = ifloor
arredondado = arredondado*(pow(10, 3) as! Float)
```

Cast from `Decimal` to unrelated type `Float` always fails.
How to solve it ?

Comment: var casas:Int=3

Comment: Try casting your arguments for `pow()` to Floats before calling the function. The pow function is overloaded - it's being resolving to a version that returns a `Decimal`, since there is no version that is defined for integers.

Comment: Why a type cast at all? The compiler is smart enough to use the proper overload of `pow`. Remove `as! Float` and the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **`powf(_:_:)`** instead of **`pow(_:_:)`**, i.e.

```
arredondado = arredondado * powf(10, 3)
```